# Visual Studio Code: Format Selection not working in PHP files with HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code version 1.63.2 with a problem.

I want to format some selection of HTML in PHP file. But the whole document is formatted as if I clicked on Format Document. How to solve this problem?

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2oo5.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ1Xh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Format HTML in PHP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sophisticode.php-formatter) extension in VS Code. Select the HTML codes you want to format in the `*.php` file and click the `Format HTML in PHP` option ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>) in the right-click menu.

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: This shortcut only formats within the area you select; does not make the selected area compatible with the file-wide format.

Comment: See my screenshots in question.

Comment: I am using [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) plugin. The difference may be due to the plugins used.

Comment: You made screenshot in HTML file - not PHP. The problem is in PHP files. Try it.

Comment: Format HTML in PHP is good solution. Thank you!